# Searching/Ordering Linked Lists Based on Class Member (C++)

Tags: c++, linq, lambda

I have a program I am creating that involves using a linked list to store my data.  Here is the definition of the node and list class:

```
template<class T>
struct Node{
    T data;
    Node *link;
};

template<class T>
class LinkedList{
private: 
    Node<T> *head;
public:
    LinkedList(){
        head = NULL;
    }
};
```

I have different classes (such as person, item, etc) that will each have their own list.  I want to be able to order these lists based on a member of the class, but I am not sure how to do this without a ton of different sorting functions.

I come from a C# background where LINQ would allow something like:

```
PersonList.OrderBy(x=>x.LastName)
```

which would order that list by the last name of the Person class.

I want to be able to do something similar in C++, but I am still green to the language and am not sure what it would entail.

Comment: Why not make things simpler and just use `std::list` for a doubly linked list or `std::forward_list` for a forward list?  Then sorting is simple by calling the `list::sort` function with the appropriate predicate function.

Comment: And once you do that, ask yourself "How did the STL list classes accomplish sorting without writing the sort code over and over again for different type `T` and using different criteria?".  That will ultimately answer your original question.   As a hint, see the prototype to the second `sort` function on this page:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort

Comment: Also, read [this](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#-c49-prefer-initialization-to-assignment-in-constructors).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay with the home-made linked list class, you need to write your sort generically, and only vary it on the "swapping" criteria.  Here is a mockup of what it would look like (note -- not compiled, so excuse any syntax errors):

```
template<class T>
  class LinkedList{
  private: 
    Node<T> *head;
    typedef bool (*cmpFunc)(T &a, T &b);

  public:
    LinkedList(){
        head = NULL;
    }

   void Sort(cmpFunc)
   {
      T* item1, *item2; 
      // whatever sorting routine you choose, doesn't matter.
      //...
      // now we are at the point in our routine where we need to compare two items
      if ( !cmpFunc(*item1, *item2) )
      {
          // we swap item1 and item2's position since the comparison
          // function says that item1 should come after item2 (the return
          // of false did this).
      }
   }
};

class Person
{
   int age;
   public:
       int getAge() const { return age; }
       Person(int n = 1) : age(n) {}
};    
...
bool CompFunction(int& i1, int& i2)
{
   return i1 > i2;  // return true if i1 > i2, false otherwise
}

bool personComp(Person& p1, Person& p2)
{
   return p1.getAge() < p2.getAge();  // sort on the age (for example)
}

LinkedList<int> l1;
//... fill it with values
l1.Sort(&CompFunction);  // will sort the ints in descending order

LinkedList<Person> p;
//... fill p with Person objects
p.Sort(&personComp);  // sorts person based on age in ascending order
```

Note that I didn't provide you the sorting routine, algorithm, etc.  The point is that whatever sorting algorithm or routine you choose, when it comes down to the comparison of two items, you call the user-defined `cmpFunc` function with those two items.

So the user provides you the function, and in that function is where the custom comparison is made.  If the function returns `true` then the arguments passed are in the right order, otherwise `false` is returned.  Your swapping routine checks the return value, and swaps the items if `false` is returned.

Note that is a crude design, but it demonstrates the basic points of how to implement a swap function when you need to use differing criteria.